# How to get controller action by passing URL in laravel

Tags: laravel

I searched more time to find how to get the controller method name by passing the URL but not found my expected answer. I want to make a method where I will pass a URL and it will give the corresponding controller action like as below but I can't figure out.

I found a helper which just return the current URL's action which is `Route::currentRouteAction()`

If a route in my application like as `Route::get('/abc', 'YourController@method')` which will generate the url `http://example.com/abc`
then how can I get the `YourController@method` by passing `http://example.com/abc`

```
   function getAction($url){
        //what will be logic?
       // return like App\Controllers\MyController@method
    }
```

I have to make a custom permission system where I need it for show and hide the menu by checking the URL of each menu.

Comment: I have updated my question, please check it @AlexeyMezenin

Answer (score 0):

Within your controller you can do the following:

```
<?php
    use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    public function index(Request $request, Router $route)
    {
        $action = $router->getRoutes()->match($request)->getActionName();

        // action should be what you're looking for.
    }
```

Comment: In controller, it will work for current route only. I have updated my question, please check it  @Rafael Berro

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you want to:

```
 Route::get('/the/url', 'YourController@method');
```

Every time anything calls the URL in the route, your method will be called.
You don't need to navigate to that url to call your method, it could be called by a form action, or a buttons action and just execute your method.

Edit:

url is your url as parameter (plain route)
import this:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
```

this is your function:

```
   public function method(Route $route, $url)
    {

        $routes = \Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes();
        foreach($routes as $r){
            if($r->getUri() == $url){
                $youraction= $r->getActionName();
               dd($youraction);
            }
           else{
                 dd('does not exist');
           }
        }
   }
```

Tested.

Comment: Your answer is for define route of application. These are already defined in my application. If a route like `Route::get('/the/url', 'YourController@method') ` then how can I get the ` YourController@method ` by passing ` /the/url `

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Just want to create a helper function which is like as what I described in my question. The parameter value will be a URL not instance. @Onix

Comment: last edit i have tested it and it works fine @Akashkhan

Comment: I have checked your code by making a function 'function getAction($url){
 $routes = Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes();
 foreach($routes as $r){
  $routeURL=url().'/'.$r->getUri();
  if($routeURL == $url){
   return $r->getActionName();
   break;
  }
 }
}' but it doesn't work for route parameter value http://localhost/l5-test/modules/6/edit @Onix

Comment: its too much to ask man, your question was not for parameters

Comment: If I find out how to do it I will let you know